APT not working as I deleted libstdc++
I just now deleted libstdc++ (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6) following some tutorial online to fix another issue.
Now, I can't get it back because trying to run apt-get errors out with:
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

.. which makes sense. My question is, how else can I reinstall this package?

Did you delete the actual library, or just the symbolic link (which should look something like /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.30?

You removed a dependency of apt, which is evident by running:
$ apt depends apt
apt
  Depends: adduser
 |Depends: gpgv
 |Depends: gpgv2
  Depends: gpgv1
  Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.12)
  Depends: ubuntu-keyring
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34)
  Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.3.1)
  Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.0)
  Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.2)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11)
  Depends: libsystemd0
  Breaks: apt-transport-https (<< 1.5~alpha4~)
  Breaks: apt-utils (<< 1.3~exp2~)
  Breaks: aptitude (<< 0.8.10)
  Recommends: ca-certificates
  Suggests: apt-doc
 |Suggests: aptitude
 |Suggests: synaptic
  Suggests: wajig
  Suggests: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.2)
 |Suggests: gnupg
 |Suggests: gnupg2
  Suggests: gnupg1
  Suggests: powermgmt-base
  Replaces: apt-transport-https (<< 1.5~alpha4~)
  Replaces: apt-utils (<< 1.3~exp2~)

You can download and install it again with wget and dpkg:
$ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libstdc++6_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i ./libstdc++6_12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb

